# How can i format the template in which the data gets downloaded in the text blob through javascript in an HTML Form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web app downloads the user input in form of a text file. How can I modify the template of the text file which is getting downloaded. Is there any way.
The current format in which it is getting downloaded is:-

```
Name: Mike
Email: xyz@gmail.com
Test type: BFT
Product Type: RAID
Protocol Type: iSCSI
IP Address: 255.255.255.0
Chasis Inputs: 21
HBA_Ports: 
MC_IP: 
MC_Netmask: 
MC_Gateway: 
MC: 
SC: 
FU: 
EC: 
Controller_ID:
```

The expected way I am looking for it to download is

```
Name: Mike
Email: xyz@gmail.com
Test type: BFT
    IP Address: 255.255.255.0
product Type: RAID
Protocol Type: iSCSI
   -Controller_ID:
   -Chasis Inputs: 21
   -HBA_Ports: 
   -MC_IP: 
   -MC_Netmask: 
   -MC_Gateway: 
   -MC: 
   -SC: 
   -FU: 
   -EC:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Save form Data in a Text File using JavaScript</title>
    <h1>User Information</h1>
    <style>
      html,
      html * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-color: teal;
        font-family: calibri;
      }
      html {
        background: radial-gradient(
          rgba(48, 97, 97, 0.5),
          rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
        );
      }

      input[type="button"],
      input[type="submit"] {
        padding: 1rem;
      }

      input[type="text"],
      textarea,
      select {
        font: 17px Calibri;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: teal;
      }
      fieldset {
        border: none;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
        font-size: 25px;
        font-style: initial;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
      }
      #extra {
        border: 2px solid black;
        background: whitesmoke;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
        width: calc(100% - 24px);
        margin: auto;
        float: none;
        clear: both;
      }
      #extra h6 {
        margin: 0;
      }
      .invalid {
        border: 2px solid red !important;
        background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const extra = {};

        const oForm = document.forms.myForm;
        const oSave = document.querySelector('input[name="save"]');
        const oSub = document.querySelector('input[name="submit"]');
        const oCtrl = document.querySelector('select[name="controller"]');
        const oTest = document.querySelector('select[name="test"]');
        const oProto = document.querySelector('select[name="protocol"]');
        const oTmp = document.querySelector("template");

        const changehandler = function(e) {
          let option = this.options[this.options.selectedIndex];

          if (option.hasAttribute("data-extra")) extra[this.name] = this.value;
          else {
            if (extra.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) delete extra[this.name];
          }

          if (Object.keys(extra).length == 2) {
            let fieldset = oTmp.content.cloneNode(true);
            oForm.insertBefore(fieldset, oProto.parentNode.nextSibling);
          } else {
            if (document.getElementById("extra")) {
              fieldset = document.getElementById("extra");
              fieldset.parentNode.removeChild(fieldset);
            }
          }

          if (option.hasAttribute("data-extra")) extra[this.name] = this.value;
          else {
            if (extra.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) delete extra[this.name];
          }
          /*
     if( option.hasAttribute( 'data-RBOD' ) ) extra[ this.name ]=this.value;
     else{
      if( extra.hasOwnProperty( this.name ) )delete extra[ this.name ];
     }
     
*/

          if (this.name == "controller") {
            if (this.value == "RAID") oProto.disabled = false;
            else oProto.disabled = true;
          }
        };

        const dialog = function(msg) {
          alert(msg);
          return false;
        };

        const savehandler = function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let valid = true;

          /*[ 'name','email','test','controller','ip','chassis' ].forEach( n => {
      oForm[ n ].classList.remove('invalid');
      if( oForm[ n ].value=='' ){
       oForm[ n ].classList.add('invalid');
       valid=false; 
      }
     });*/
          if (!valid) return dialog("Please fill all the fields!");

          const reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
          if (reg.test(oForm.email.value) == false) {
            return dialog("Invalid Email Address");
          }

          const ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
          if (ipformat.test(oForm.ip.value) == false) {
            return dialog("Invalid IP Address");
          }

          if (oForm.name.value.length < 3)
            return dialog("Name must be having atleast 3 Characters");

          let data = {
            Name: oForm.name.value,
            Email: oForm.email.value,
            "Test type": oForm.test.value,
            "Product Type": oForm.controller.value,
            "Protocol Type": oForm.protocol.value,
            "IP Address": oForm.ip.value,
            "Chasis Inputs": oForm.chassis.value
          };

          if (Object.keys(extra).length == 2) {
            data["HBA_Ports"] = oForm["hba-ports"].value;
            data["MC_IP"] = oForm["extra-ip"].value;
            data["MC_Netmask"] = oForm["netmask-ip"].value;
            data["MC_Gateway"] = oForm["gateway-ip"].value;
            data["MC"] = oForm["rbod-mc"].value;
            data["SC"] = oForm["rbod-sc"].value;
            data["FU"] = oForm["rbod-fu"].value;
            data["EC"] = oForm["rbod-ec"].value;
            data["Controller_ID"] = oForm["Controller-ID"].value;
          }
          let payload = Object.keys(data)
            .map(key => {
              return [key, data[key]].join(": ");
            })
            .join(String.fromCharCode(10));

          const blob = new Blob([payload], { type: "text/plain" });
          const file = "formData.yaml";

          let link = document.createElement("a");
          link.download = file;

          if (window.webkitURL != null) {
            link.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
          } else {
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(link);
          }
          link.click();
        };

        oCtrl.addEventListener("change", changehandler);
        oTest.addEventListener("change", changehandler);
        oSave.addEventListener("click", savehandler);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <template>
      <fieldset id="extra">
        <h6>Additional Details Required</h6>
        <label for="Controller_ID">Controller_ID:</label>
        <select name="Controller-ID" required>
          <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
          <option value="A">A </option
          ><option value="B">B </option></select
        >

        <label for="HBA_Ports">HBA_Ports:</label
        ><input
          type="text"
          name="hba-ports"
          placeholder="Enter the HBA Ports"
        />
        <label for="MC_IP">MC_IP:</label
        ><input type="text" name="extra-ip" placeholder="Enter the MC_IP" />
        <label for="MC_Netmask">MC_Netmask:</label
        ><input
          type="text"
          name="netmask-ip"
          placeholder="Enter the MC_Netmask"
        />
        <label for="MC_Gateway">MC_Gateway:</label
        ><input
          type="text"
          name="gateway-ip"
          placeholder="Enter the MC_Gateway"
        />
        <label for="MC">MC:</label
        ><input type="text" name="rbod-mc" placeholder="Enter the MC Port" />
        <label for="SC">SC:</label
        ><input type="text" name="rbod-sc" placeholder="Enter the SC Port" />
        <label for="FU">FU:</label
        ><input type="text" name="rbod-fu" placeholder="Enter the FU Port" />
        <label for="EC">EC:</label
        ><input type="text" name="rbod-ec" placeholder="Enter the EC Port" />
      </fieldset>
    </template>

    <form name="myForm" method="POST">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Enter your Email Id"
          required
        />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <label for="Controller Type">Controller Type</label>
        <select name="controller" required>
          <option value=""> - Select the Controller - </option>
          <option data-extra="true" value="RAID">RAID </option
          ><option value="JBOD">JBOD </option
          ><option value="AP">AP </option></select
        >
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <label for="Test Type">Test Type</label>
        <select name="test" required>
          <option value=""> - Select The Test - </option>
          <option data-extra="true" value="BFT">BFT </option
          ><option data-extra="true" value="CTO">CTO </option
          ><option data-extra="true" value="RAID Generic">RAID Generic </option
          ><option data-extra="true" value="Port Check">Port Check </option
          ><option data-extra="true" value="FW Generic">FW Generic </option
          ><option data-extra="true" value="JBOD Generic"
            >JBOD Generic
          </option></select
        >
      </fieldset>

      <!-- insert templated additional details here -->

      <fieldset>
        <label for="Protocol Type">Protocol Type</label>
        <select name="protocol" disabled>
          <option selected hidden disabled> - Select The Protocol - </option
          ><option data-extra="true" value="SAS">SAS </option
          ><option data-extra="true" value="iSCSI">iSCSI </option
          ><option data-extra="true" value="FC">FC </option></select
        >
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <label for="IP Address">IP Address:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="ip"
          placeholder="Enter your IP address"
          required
        />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <label for="Chasis Input">Number of Chasis Input:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="chassis"
          placeholder="Enter Number of Chasis"
          required
        />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <input type="button" name="save" value="Save data to file" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't see much difference between the current result and the expected one. is it only the fields order? if that's it, just choose the right in the let data= part

Comment: i needed the expected data in indented form after Protocol Type with a '-' one below the other. My expected output couldn't be captured properly in the question. Apologies for that. I have edited the expected and actual just now

Comment: no pb ;) I guess the easiest way is to add the indent in the data keys... if you don't want to add an extra hardcoded list of indent to add

Comment: can you please help me how can i do that. I tried text-indent and also tried to indent manually the different select options, yet was was unable to do it

Comment: in the javascript data gathering part try `data["      - HBA_Ports"]` instead of `data["HBA_Ports"]`